# How to refresh JS code shown by Firefox Developer Edition in the Debugger pane?

Tags: javascript, refresh, firefox-developer-edition

Within the Debugger pane of FDE, I can easily display my JS code that's embedded in my PHP page. But if I change the source code and hit F5, it is still the former version of the code that is shown. I tried Ctrl+F5, but it is still the same version. Note that the JS code is embedded inside the HTML page, so it's not like it comes from a separate cached .js file.

The only way I've found to refresh the code is to...close FDE and load the URL back in it!

Is there a way to easily refresh the embedded JS code, like I used to do with  a simple F5 with Firefox+Firebug?

Comment: try `F12` > `settings` > `disable http cache (when toolbox is open)` and then reload

Comment: Wishful idea, but nope, no cigar.

Comment: Update: there was a mistake on the JS line in that file. But now that the mistake has been fixed (and tested ok with FF56), I can see a difference: the breakpoint flickers as I click on the line number, but won't stay. It just flicks on and off for a split second. Both the style on the line number, and the entry in the breakpoint pane on the far right. Note that I closed FDE and reopened it since. The behaviour stays the same.

Comment: Did you ever come across a solution for this? I've started running into it myself and it is a real pain...

Comment: I wish this would get fixed.  Apparently it was an issue years ago and they fixed it then.  but it's sure not fixed now.

Comment: I am also unable to refresh the javascript code while on the debugger.